# how to use x3d in browser without x3dom.js

Tags: javascript, html, x3d, x3dom

I have read a paper, X3DOM - A DOM-based HTML5/X3D Integration Model,which provids some examples.However i can't run these code.
  I have known how to use X3D with x3dom.js in browser, i want know if i can use x3d like below example.Like author said ,if i want to use these code, it is important to use the ".xhtml" suffix to instruct Firefox .I have done according to his requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
X3D DOM integration and manipulation
</title></head>
<body>
<h1>X3D DOM integration and manipulation</h1>
<x3d:x3d xmlns:x3d=
"http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.xsd">
<x3d:Scene>
<x3d:Shape>
<x3d:Box x3d:size="4 4 4" />
</x3d:Shape>
</x3d:Scene> 
</x3d:x3d>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the paper.http://www.web3d.org/wiki/images/3/30/X3dom-web3d2009-paper.pdf

Comment: In case you didn't realize, the paper you linked is a _proposal_ for integrating X3D into the DOM. It is not documentation for something that is currently implemented.

Comment: Patrick Roberts: It is implemented. See http:.//x3dom.org/. It is not a complete implementation of all of the features in X3D, but X3DOM + HTML/DOM covers everything that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

X3DOM is a JavaScript library that needs to be included to handle the X3D tags. Without the library and corresponding CSS, it won't be able to parse the tags and attributes and provide DOM interaction.

The paper discussed a mechanism for having a browser to implement 3D inside of an HTML document. To date. the W3C has not adopt any 3D mechanism as a standard. The browser builders are working with a number of ideas, but nothing has been standardized.

I wrote a blog post about how to add X3D to your webpage - http://realism.com/blog/add-x3d-your-webpage